# change style in looping button react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i just start to learn react native [i want to make ui like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t5PY.png),
i want the buttons on the image work like radio button, so user just can choose a button and change the button style choosed by user, and bellow is my code

```
class ButtonOption extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data : [],
      active : 0
    };
  }

   loadButton(temp){
     let result = [];
     for (let i =0;i<temp.length;i++){
       if(i==this.state.active){
         result.push(
         <View key={i} style={buttonOption.main}>
           <TouchableOpacity style={buttonOption.tabActive} onPress={()=>{this.setState({active:i});alert(this.state.active)}}>
             <Text style={buttonOption.labelActive}>{temp[i]}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>)
       }else{
         result.push(
         <View key={i} style={buttonOption.main}>
           <TouchableOpacity style={buttonOption.tab} onPress={()=>{this.setState({active:i});alert(this.state.active)}}>
             <Text style={buttonOption.label}>{temp[i]}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>)
       }
     }
     return result;
   }

   componentDidMount(){
     this.setState({data:this.loadButton(this.props.arrButton)})
   }

   render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row',padding:10}}>
        {this.state.data}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default ButtonOption;
```

on code above i was try to make button with looping, in looping function i use active as a state for check active button, and add function onPress so everytime user click button, active state will change, but when i run and choose button the active state won't change, what is wronge with my onPress code, can someone help please?

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Too broad&unclear question.

Comment: state active won't change

Comment: Edit your question to include relevant information please. Information in comments have no value.

Comment: im sorry, i changed my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might know the answer, You have generated the view using this.loadButton and saved it in this.state.data. This is done one time only. when the render method is called. It is expecting a new view based on states but this.state.data is not changing since you create it in componentDidMount. What you need to do is to call this.loadButton(this.props.arrButton) in render method. this will create new view every time render method is called.

```
render() {
 return (
   <View style={{flexDirection:'row',padding:10}}>
     {this.loadButton(this.props.arrButton)}
   </View>
 );
}
```

This might do it, If you still have any error, please report.